# Pass onPostExecute result to new Activity

Tags: android, json, android-activity

I wrote a splash activity with an async call to download JSON from a URL. In  `onPostExecute` I get JSON as a result. Now I need to pass that JSON to a new activity to parse and display it in `listView`. Do I need to start that new activity before or after I have passed the JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the resulting JSON available to the new activity by using `putExtra` in `onPostExecute` right before starting the new activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, yourClass.class);
intent.putExtra("json", json);
// Now start your activity
```

You can then get the json by calling `getString` in your new activity.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
jsonString = extras.getString("json");
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you pull the data from your JSON Object (String, int, etc) then pass it off as Extra object for the intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),ResultsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("extraname", "extravalue");
intent.putExtra("extraname2", 9.99);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then on your newly created activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);
String extra = getIntent().getStringExtra("extraname") //returns null if nothing
Double extra2 = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("extraname2")
```